# DOMPDF Calculation

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, dompdf, calculated-field

[PHP Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsddz.jpg)
I have not understand what I have to do on this to show the net value.

It doesn't show me any value. What should I do please help me.[PDF File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEOGu.jpg)

Here is the table code. I can't see the shipping charge net value in table footer.

```
  <table width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" class="estilo4"><CENTER><strong> <h1>Payment</h1></strong></CENTER></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr bgcolor="black" border="1" solid  #5D6975 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <th class="estilo1">'.$TRACK.'</th>
                    <th class="estilo1">'.$zones.'</th>
                    <th class="estilo1">'.$FECHA.'</th>
                    <th class="estilo1">'.$Mer.'</th>
                    <th class="estilo1">'.$DESTINA.'</th>
                    <th class="estilo1">'.$NUMBERPHONE.'</th>
                    <th class="estilo1">'.$ESTADO.'</th>
                    <th class="estilo1">'.$deliveryboy.'</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                <tbody>
                ';

                $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM courier_online WHERE payment = 'OK' AND email='$qname' AND date   BETWEEN '$desde' AND '$hasta'");
                while($express=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $initial = 0; // Empezar a contar desde 0
                $initial = $initial + $row['shipping_subtotal'];
                $codigoHTML.='  
                    <tr>
                        <td class="estilo3">'.$express['cons_no'].'</td>
                        <td class="estilo3">'.$express['shipping_subtotal'].'</td>
                        <td class="estilo3">'.$express['date'].'</td>
                        <td class="estilo3">'.$express['user'].'</td>
                        <td class="estilo3">'.$express['rev_name'].'</td>
                        <td class="estilo3">'.$express['r_phone'].'</td>
                        <td class="estilo3">'.$express['status'].'</td> 
                        <td class="estilo3"></td>                           
                    </tr>   
                </tbody>
<tfoot>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;" rowspan="1">
                                                            <b><?php echo $initial; ?></b>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tfoot>                
                    ';

                }
        $codigoHTML.='

              </table>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code. And not a picture of your code.

Comment: nothing particular to do with pdf creation either.

Comment: `$initial +=$row[....];`

Comment: @rtfm - huh? Why are you posting a random line of code?

Comment: @DavidMakogon its not random, see OP's code.

Comment: @rtfm - it *is* random: the OP didn't embed any code, so nobody has context unless they click through to view a screencap of the code (which is not how questions should be set up, and why the question has been downvoted). And you've provided no context to the code you posted and why it's relevant.

Comment: wow clicking a link is so hard. OP has highlighted the variable and asked what it would be, which is exactly what i provided.

Comment: I have edited my post. I added my table code.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with your code:

1) You're `echo`ing the value of `$initial` rather than concatenating it to the value of your `$codigoHTML` variable. Because of this it is not included in the HTML document (as contained in the variable).

2) Your generated HTML is not valid. You should move the closing TBODY tag and the entire TFOOT block outside the closing brace for the `while` loop.

Comment: Would please change the code? I requested you. I don't understand. I need subtotal value.<span class="text-white font-thin h1 block">
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(shipping_subtotal) as total FROM courier_customer WHERE  correo='".$_SESSION["user_name"]."' AND payment='Pending'");   
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    echo $s.formato($row["total"]); 
    
    ?></span>